# Lag when is used clipShape and Circle on SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am facing a problem with SwiftUI's `clipShape()`.

When I use `clipShape()` with `Circle()`, my iPad (iPad air 2) is lagging + black screen but with Capsule I haven't this lag.

This GIF presents you this problem :
[clipShape with circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/borIR.gif)

And this GIF presents you `clipShape()` with `Capsule()` where I don't see any problem :
[clipShape with capsule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3e56.gif)

This is the code I used to test this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(1 ..< 5) { i in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(1 ..< 15) { t in
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.